# Improve query performance in 300 million rows table

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I need to improve the performance of a query which takes way too long. The query is used in an SSIS data flow in the source task. It is part of a longer query but this is what causes the problem so I narrowed it down as follows:

```
select xa.*, s.idA 
from tableA s 
inner join tableB xa on s.idA = xa.idB
where xa.type = 'type_A'
```

- TableA = 80 million rows
- TableB = 340 million rows

`TableA` has a non clustered index on `idA` and `TableB` a non clustered index on `idB`. The execution plan uses the index of `TableA` and performs a full table scan on `TableB` which takes 98% of the effort. I have tried to create a non clustered index on `TableB`, on column `idB` including column `Type`. I had to kill the create query after an hour because it was suspended with a CXPACKET wait type. Probably it was waiting to read all the data but my SSIS flows can't afford to waste resources for so much time. I then tried to create a clustered index on tableB column type, which I thought would take less time. The plan was to modify the query using a cte like this:

```
;with tmp as 
(
     select * 
     from tableB 
     where type = 'Type_A'
)
select xa.*, s.idA 
from tableA s 
inner join tmp xa on s.idA = xa.idB
```

Using this query i will have only 200k rows in the tmp table and i will avoid full table scan to filter tableB utilizing all the available indexes so i think it will reasonably improve the speed

However, i had to kill the create query as it was taking more than 1 hour (suspended again, CXPACKET again). So my question is: Is it possible to speed up the index creation process? Is it possible to estimate the time needed for the index creation?

Comment: So the question is not about improving the query but how to create an index on  a large table? Does [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41161/609#) help?

Comment: I suggest you create a _filtered_ index using `type = 'type_A'` since this is hard coded in your query. If the filter is selective it's quite possible that it will be created much faster because it has to load less rows. Of course it still has to find them in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Moving criteria to a subquery (CTE) is not the solution. You are supposed to use SQL to tell the DBMS what to get, not how to get it. It's the DBMS's task to find the optimal plan. So write the query as readable as possible and help the DBMS by providing appropriate indexes.

You should have the following indexes for the query:

```
create index idx1 on tableB ( type, idB ); -- to find B quickly and have the ID ready for the join
create index idx2 on tableA ( idA );
```

(It looks strange that you join on idA = idB, but I guess that's just in the example, right?)

Comment: Well, he tried that already. The question is misleading. Actually he can't create the index because the table is large and it stops after an hour. In my opinion he just needs to be more patient.

Comment: Thank you both. Tim's comment provides a link with a few suggestions to speed up the indexing process. Will try it. It is not a lack of patience, there are data flows running that get slowed down due to the i/o the index creation needs and everything moves back. Can't afford this so i am trying to keep it within an hour or so.